# Error XAAAS7001: System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I just installed Visual Studio 2019, and I created a Xamarin.Forms project. When I tried to execute it in the android emulator, I get this error :

> Gravité Code Description Projet Fichier Ligne État de la suppression Erreur XAAAS7001: System.NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet. à Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidApkSigner.AddStorePass(CommandLineBuilder cmd, String cmdLineSwitch, String value) à Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidApkSigner.GenerateCommandLineCommands() à Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() à Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidToolTask.RunTask() dans /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidToolTask.cs:ligne 24 à Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidToolTask.Execute() dans /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidToolTask.cs:ligne 15 0

Some information:

- Visual Studio 2019 v16.11.12
- Windows 10
- NetStandard 2.0
- Emulator Pixel 2 R 11.0- API30 android 11.0

Comment: Rebuild Solution - get the same error again?

Comment: You could share some code of your project so we can get more detail

Answer (score 0):

I just update the Visual Studio and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include what version of Visual Studio you updated to in order to fix this? That will help future readers help identify what the floor of support is for expecting this issue to be resolved. (E.g., if they encounter this issue with a higher version, that might help them identify that this won't solve the issue for them.)